# rspec_api_documentation resources can have explanations. So why they don't show in raddocs html?

Tags: rspec-api-documentation

Resources in RspecApiDocumentation can have explanations. But they don't show when using `json` format with `raddocs` html browser.

Example:

user_spec.rb:

```
resource 'User' do
  explanation "a User resource, duh"
...
```

index.json:

```
{
      "name": "User",
      "explanation": "a User resource, duh"
      ...
}
```

But the explanation doesn't appear in the resulting html:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using raddocs v 1.1. The support for resource explanation is introduced in raddocs v 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but the cause was different. The `explanation` command only works in a `resource` or an `example`. If you attempt to put multiple `explanation` at other places, then no corresponding output is produced.

Comment: I think this would have been better as a comment :)